# is there a shortcut to expand folders in Finder while being in Cover Flow mode?

Tags: finder, shortcut

in Finder I can use the arrow keys to go up and down and with "left arrow" and "right arrow" I can expand a folder while being in List View mode.
However, when I'm in Cover Flow mode the "left arrow" and "right arrow" do the same as "up arrow" and "down arrow", i.e. just go up and down in the list.
How can I expand a folder while being in Cover Flow?

Answer (score 1):

aaaand while typing the question I just played around and figured it out:

In order to expand a folder you need to use COMMAND+"left arrow" and COMMAND+"right arrow" respectively.